# Python: Compiling with Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

So I'm trying to create a executable binary file with Pyinstaller. Upon building the file 'warnpython.txt' appears bearing this message.

```
W: no module named msvcrt (conditional import by subprocess)
W: no module named msvcrt (delayed import by getpass)
W: no module named rourl2path (conditional import by urllib)
W: no module named msvcrt (conditional import by getpass)
W: no module named _subprocess (conditional import by subprocess)
W: no module named AES (delayed, conditional import by archive)
W: no module named _scproxy (conditional import by urllib)
W: no module named org (top-level import by pickle)
W: no module named EasyDialogs (conditional import by getpass)
W: no module named SOCKS (top-level import by ftplib)
W: no module named _winreg (delayed import by urllib)
W: no module named nt (top-level import by ntpath)
W: no module named org (top-level import by copy)
W: no module named _emx_link (conditional import by os)
W: __all__ is built strangely at line 0 - __future__ (/usr/lib/python2.6/__future__.pyc)
W: __all__ is built strangely at line 0 - collections (/usr/lib/python2.6/collections.pyc)
W: delayed  exec statement detected at line 0 - collections (/usr/lib/python2.6/collections.pyc)
W: delayed  __import__ hack detected at line 0 - email (/usr/lib/python2.6/email/__init__.pyc)
W: delayed  __import__ hack detected at line 0 - encodings (/usr/lib/python2.6/encodings/__init__.pyc)
W: delayed  __import__ hack detected at line 0 - optparse (/usr/lib/python2.6/optparse.pyc)
W: delayed  exec statement detected at line 0 - socket (/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.pyc)
W: delayed conditional __import__ hack detected at line 0 - doctest (/usr/lib/python2.6/doctest.pyc)
W: delayed  exec statement detected at line 0 - doctest (/usr/lib/python2.6/doctest.pyc)
W: delayed conditional __import__ hack detected at line 0 - doctest (/usr/lib/python2.6/doctest.pyc)
W: __all__ is built strangely at line 0 - dis (/usr/lib/python2.6/dis.pyc)
W: delayed  eval hack detected at line 0 - os (/usr/lib/python2.6/os.pyc)
W: delayed conditional __import__ hack detected at line 0 - unittest (/usr/lib/python2.6/unittest.pyc)
W: delayed conditional __import__ hack detected at line 0 - unittest (/usr/lib/python2.6/unittest.pyc)
W: __all__ is built strangely at line 0 - tokenize (/usr/lib/python2.6/tokenize.pyc)
W: delayed  exec statement detected at line 0 - bdb (/usr/lib/python2.6/bdb.pyc)
W: delayed  eval hack detected at line 0 - bdb (/usr/lib/python2.6/bdb.pyc)
W: delayed  eval hack detected at line 0 - bdb (/usr/lib/python2.6/bdb.pyc)
W: delayed  __import__ hack detected at line 0 - pickle (/usr/lib/python2.6/pickle.pyc)
W: delayed  __import__ hack detected at line 0 - pickle (/usr/lib/python2.6/pickle.pyc)
W: delayed conditional exec statement detected at line 0 - iu (/home/zack/Desktop/pyinstaller-1.5-rc1/iu.pyc)
W: delayed conditional exec statement detected at line 0 - iu (/home/zack/Desktop/pyinstaller-1.5-rc1/iu.pyc)
W: delayed  eval hack detected at line 0 - gettext (/usr/lib/python2.6/gettext.pyc)
W: delayed conditional eval hack detected at line 0 - warnings (/usr/lib/python2.6/warnings.pyc)
W: delayed conditional __import__ hack detected at line 0 - warnings (/usr/lib/python2.6/warnings.pyc)
W: delayed  exec statement detected at line 0 - pdb (/usr/lib/python2.6/pdb.pyc)
W: delayed conditional eval hack detected at line 0 - pdb (/usr/lib/python2.6/pdb.pyc)
W: delayed  eval hack detected at line 0 - pdb (/usr/lib/python2.6/pdb.pyc)
W: delayed conditional eval hack detected at line 0 - pdb (/usr/lib/python2.6/pdb.pyc)
W: delayed  eval hack detected at line 0 - pdb (/usr/lib/python2.6/pdb.pyc)
```

Directly after executing the newly made executable file I'm dropped back to terminal as if the process has exited. When tested via executing the py script everything works fine it's only when it's compiled with Pyinstaller does this happen. Does the warning file give us any clues?

Comment: It's not an answer, but cx_Freeze might be a replacement that would work for you: http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Old question, but just for documentation: you should activate the debug mode, to see how bad it runs, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7879465/compiling-python-code-into-a-single-exe/7903310#7903310 for details.

Answer (score 2):

looks like the module pywin32 is missing in your system. try install ActivePython or install the pywin32 module.

http://python.net/crew/mhammond/win32/Downloads.html