# Packing a Python program to an executable (including python?)

Tags: python, executable

I have completed the log parsing script including a simple GUI and I am wondering. Is it possible to pack the whole thing into one file (.exe prefferably) that would carry even the python itself, so it can be launched from stations without python+modules installation? Perhaps wrap it in C? I am quite new to programming world, hence the question may sound stupid.

I have tried to look at py2exe and pyInstaller, but didnt find a way to pack it "all". Script is written in Python 2.7.3 using GTK2x and some additional modules (dateutil, colorama).

Comment: py2exe is exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7879465/compiling-python-code-into-a-single-exe)**.
You should know that a python program compiled will give you a huge executable file (5 or more MB) because it adds python into your executable, which means that even a simple one-liner program (for example : `print("hello world")` ) will give you a big .exe file

Comment: Yep, I know about the size issues, but they are of a secondary concern in my particular case. First priority is to "make it executable on any random workstation" which sadly disqualifies any other method.
And thanks for the link, Ill look into it as soon as I can!